# Create a new Button on a LinearLayout in Android

Tags: android, sdk, android-linearlayout

once again a question of a newcomer among the android people.

I have pretty much everything through to answers that I could find here.
Unfortunately, nothing is running out.

I just want a (back) button to add.
I get no error message, but to me the button is not displayed.

Can someone help me here one?

Timo

```
Button btn = new Button(this); 
btn.setText("Zurück"); 
btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
btn.setHeight(10);
btn.setWidth(100);

LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_main);
linearLayout.addView(btn, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

Button buttonNews = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_news);
buttonNews.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Button buttonWeather = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_weather);
buttonWeather.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Button buttonTraffic = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_traffic);
buttonTraffic.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

---

Set die height from the Button over 48....

Unfortunately this has no effect.

a question for understanding ...

LinearLayout linear layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.layout_main);

layout_main is the layoutID here?

That is in the main.xml is it currently so with me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main"
     >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:minHeight="92dp"
        android:onClick="onMyButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/btn_news"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_traffic"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:minHeight="92dp"
        android:onClick="onMyButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/btn_traffic"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_weather"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="57dp"
        android:minHeight="92dp"
        android:onClick="onMyButtonClick"
        android:text="@string/btn_weather"
        android:textSize="22sp" >
</Button>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listMainView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The button height value of `10` is too small. Try set to `48` or higher, because 48dp is the recommended minimum size of a button so that user won't feel cramped when pressing it. Also, are you sure you are inflating the right view? You mentioned that you called layout_main but it shows that you inflated `R.id.layout_global`.

Comment: Unfortunately this has no effect.

a question for understanding ...

  LinearLayout linear layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.layout_main);

layout_main is the layout here?

That is in the main.xml is it currently so with me.

Comment: When you call findViewById(R.id.layout_main), it will look up the view with id "layout_main" which is located in  the layout file where you called `setContentView(R.layout.some_layout)`, for example. In this case there should be a some_layout.xml in you res/ folder.

Answer (score 0):

Set your button height properly and then see what happen.. this is the only reason you cant see your button in liearlayout..

Comment: ok, i have set

btn.setHeight(100);
btn.setWidth(100);
btn.setTextSize(33);

and yes, i will look the layout "layout_main". I have corrected this in my post.

These changes have not brought.
Do I maybe put the button in the fore or say it should be placed before the list?